# Difference between cat filename and cat < filename in unix

Tags: unix, cat

Suppose I have a file named "file1". I want to display the contents of "file1" using the `cat` command in Unix.

Both `cat file1` and `cat < file1` are working similarly. What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's where input comes from.

- If you say `cat file1` the shell doesn't do anything special. **`cat` calls `open(2)` on the file** and reads from it
- If you say `cat < file1` **the shell calls `open(2)` on the file** and calls `dup(2)` into `STDIN_FILENO` for `cat`. `cat` just reads from `STDIN_FILENO`

Comment: Can you please tell me what are these open(2),dup(2),STDIN_FILENO ? @cnicutar

Comment: These are system calls and are documented in manual pages. SO for example when I say `open(2)` I mean `man 2 open`, that is the manual entry for `open` in section 2.

Answer (score 1):

We can use another command to notice the difference between:

```
wc –w food2.txt
```

Possible output:

```
6 food2.txt
```

the command tells the file name since it knows it (passed as an argument) .

```
wc –w < food2.txt
```

Possible output:

```
6
```

the standard input is redirected to file food2.txt without the command knowing about it .

Answer (score 0):

`cat` opens a file, and `cat > fileName` tells the shell to open the file in the cat standard input.

Here is a link with more detailed information/answer: 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258931/difference-between-cat-and-cat